# What is key_ordinal = 0 for index columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

In MSSQL, I have index on a partitioned table, for which I dont understand the meaning of the property `key_ordinal` when it's equal to zero.

To create the index, the partition scheme is based on CUT_OFF.

```
create table dbo.TESTTB (CUT_OFF datetime, number int) on partscheme(CUT_OFF);
create index TESTIX on dbo.TESTTB (number) on partscheme(CUT_OFF);
```

The query shows the values of **key_ordinal**:

```
select c.name as column_name, b.key_ordinal
from sys.indexes a
inner join sys.index_columns b 
    on  a.object_id = b.object_id and  a.index_id = b.index_id
inner join sys.all_columns c on b.object_id = c.object_id
    and b.column_id = c.column_id 
where a.name = 'TESTIX'
```

The results are:

```
column_name key_ordinal
CUT_OFF     0
number      1
```

The column **CUT_OFF**:

- Is showed in `sys.index_columns` with **key_ordinal = 0**
- Is missing in `Create Index` statement
- Is missing in index information from `sp_help 'TESTTB'`

[MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175105.aspx)

> 0 = Not a key column, or is an XML index, a columnstore index, or a
>   spatial index.

What does it means?
What is **key_ordinal = 0**?

Thanks

Comment: You're partitioning a heap table, since you've created no clustered index (either explicitly or implicitly as the primary key). Is that really what you want to do? It's an unusual scenario, to say the least, and probably the explanation for the weird `key_ordinal`.

Comment: I think it's similar to the situation described under `is_included_column`: "Columns implicitly added because they are a partitioning column are returned as 0."

Comment: "0 = Not a key column", -  looks like this is your case.

Comment: You are right, it should be something like implicit column. I must generate "create" scripts and run them at runtime, based on existing tables: that's why I don't have CUT_OFF for index (it's missing also in original table). Stil, I dont get what exactly does **"Not a key column"** means: column is invisible for indexing purpose, but it's used the same to partition data?

Comment: As I understand this, "Not a key column" means that it is added to the leaf level of the index, but not to the intermediate and root levels. So it is not a key, but rather INCLUDE column. In this case this INCLUDE column added to the index implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is added to the index implicitly to the leaf level (like INCLUDE column). Therefore, it is not a key column. Below are screenshots of the output of DBCC PAGE for this index.

Root level:

[image]

Leaf Level:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is an INCLUDE column? Thanks

Comment: Sure. I mean this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx columns which are added to the nonclustered index using the INCLUDE keyword. They are added to the leaf level and preventing the Key or RID lookup if all data needed by the query can be found in the included or key columns of the nonclustered index.